Does there exist a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \{(-1)^na_n^2\}=1$, $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$
Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of $x$. I need an example of a sequence with all positive terms $(a_n^2)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \{(-1)^na_n^2\}=1\text{
and } \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^2=\infty$.
If the sequence is convergent to $1$, then the subsequence of even and odd powers will also converge to $1$. So we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \{(-1)^{2n}a_{2n}^2\}=1 \text{ and } \lim_{n\to\infty} \{(-1)^{2n-1}a_{2n-1}^2\}=1$.
So we have $\lim_{n\to\infty} \{a_{2n}^2\}=1\text{ and } \lim_{n\to\infty} \{-a_{2n-1}^2\}=1$. Since $a_{n}^2>0,\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ so we have $\{-x\}=1-\{x\}$. $\lim_{n\to\infty} \{a_{2n}^2\}=1\text{ and }\lim_{n\to\infty}(1-\{a_{2n-1}^2\})=1$.
Therefore we obtain $\lim_{n\to\infty} \{a_{2n}^2\}=1\text{ and } \lim_{n\to\infty} \{a_{2n-1}^2\}=0$.
I think that due to the presence of $(-1)^n$, the limit will oscillate and does not exist. Any help will be highly appreciated.

@mick Sorry, but I did not get you. Please elaborate.

Which definition you use for fractional part of a negative number? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part#For_negative_numbers

@mick Please wait. I am talking about the fractional part of $(-1)^n a_n$

@Andrei Since Thanks. I am using the definition ${-x}=1-{x}$ and ${x}=x-[x]$, where $x>0$ and $[x]$ is the greatest integer $\leq x$.

Was this generated by ChatGPT?

@copper.hat No. Actually my Professor gave me this question.

@max ok so lets say $a_n^2$ gets closer to an integer and grows to infinity. That is the question and the answer : by definition. done ?

By this definition of fractional part of negative integers, e.g. $-2$, $${-2} = 1-{2} = 1 - 2+\lfloor2\rfloor = 1$$ so it's easy to find a sequence that gives $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left{-a_{2n-1}^2\right} = 1$.

@peterwhy This definition of fractional part is only for $x$ not an integer.

Let $a_{n}^2=n+(-1)^{n+1}2^{-n}.$ Clearly $a_{n}^2\to \infty.$ We have $$(-1)^na_{n}^2= (-1)^nn-1+(1-2^{-n}) $$ Thus $$\{(-1)^na_n^2\}=1-2^{-n}\to 1$$

I have added more details.

Thank you so much.
